# Bridged routers - can route one way but not the other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, openwrt, wireless-bridge

I have a SKY router (D-Link DSL-2640S) which is my main router and a TP-Link TL-MR34220 which is connected wirelessly to the SKY one. I have OpenWRT on the TP-Link.

I have a Raspberry Pi and a WD NAS that are wired connected to the TP-Link, (I don't need it to be wireless because of it's location) and they both have Internet access.

So the Raspi, NAS and TP-Link can all see the SKY router and any devices connected wirelessly to it. But I can't get any wirelessly connected devices to see the TP-Link or Raspi or NAS.

My IP settings for the SKY router are:
192.168.0.1
255.255.255.0

Settings for TP-Link are:
192.168.1.1 (LAN)
255.255.255.0

I have tried changing the IP of the TP-Link so it's 192.168.0.2 - DHCP on SKY doesn't start until 192.168.0.100, and I don't have DHCP on the TP-LInk - but then I can't connect it to the SKY router.

I have followed every guide I can find and I'm unable to get the configuration right so I think I'm missing a fundamental understanding of this.

All I want to do is SSH to the Raspi from my laptop which is connected to the SKY router. 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Disable routing, `dnsmasq`, the "SPI firewall", and DHCP on the TP-Link.  This is easily done through DD-WRT's interface.  All of that should be set up on your "SKY" router and not the TP-Link.

Clients connected wirelessly or through LAN ports will pull DHCP and default gateway information from your "SKY" router.